# What should I do to lose weight?

Tags: body-fat, muscle-gain

I'm 6 foot, 330 pounds. I'm 18 years old and I've been big all my life. I want to lose body fat and build muscle. I work out everyday now. I don't know if I should focus more on my workout or my cardio... Before I've just focused on lighter weight and more reps, then I now do more cardio than weights. I'd rather lift more weights than do more cardio. Someone please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you should focus on both with the same weight, 50% cardio, 50% weight lifting. I suggest you do a 3-day Workout where you do your full body every workout, that help's you to get a good basic for later weight lifting. On off days you put in 20-40 min of cardio, try especially HIIT Cardio (just google what it means and how it works), it will help you burn fat a lot faster. So you could do something like this:

- Monday: Full Body Workout (1-2 Exercises per Body part, chest back
  shoulders abs legs biceps & triceps)
- Tuesday: 20-40 Min of HIIT Cardio, outside or in the gym doesn't
  really matter
- Wednesday: Full Body Workout
- Thursday: 20-40 Min of HIIT Cardio
- Friday: Full Body Workout
- Saturday: 20-40 Min of HIIT Cardio
- Sunday: Rest Day, don't do anything and just get ready for the Monday
  workout

Why i can relate to this?

I was on a similar point at what you are right now, and this plan really helped me out to build up some basic muscles and burn fat, after 3-4 Month i switched it up, but i think it should help in the beginning.

Good links i can provide to you are:

[bodybuilding.com](http://bodybuilding.com)

[muscleandstrength.com](http://muscleandstrength.com)

They both have a ton of workout routines and exercises, check them out and experiment. You will soon recognize which exercises you may want to keep doing or some that you really dont like.

If you have any questions just hit me up in the comments :) Hope it gave you a good beginning on how to start,

cheers Budd.

Answer (score 1):

### Diet

Look I'm going to be honest, the biggest factor in you losing weight will be your diet. Cardio helps, doing weights helps, but the primary factor is always diet. A lot of cardio and weights cannot overcome a bad diet. But that doesn't mean ignore them - they are important to complement a good diet and will help your results!

With that out of the way, doing more weights than cardio is fine. Once diet is on plan, you should find the combination of weights and cardio that helps you **stay motivated** and **reach your goals**.

### Some Suggestions

I strongly suggest using heavier weights for sets of 5 - 15. Low weights for lots of reps is going to waste your time. You need to build serious muscle, it will help you look in shape much faster.

The plan Noshii outlined in his(?) answer is a good start, but don't feel limited to lifting only a few times a week. If you like it then lift as much as you want. 5 times a week, 6 times, 7 times a week is fine. You can aim for a minimum of cardio (twice a week is great) and lift as much as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do lots of cardio to burn your fat, as long as you are willing to eat much less than you've been doing previously.

Based on your preferences, this is what I would do:

1. [Calculate your TDEE](http://www.iifym.com/tdee-calculator/) based on your activity level and substract at least 25-30%. This will be your caloric goal.
2. Buy a food scale and start measuring -if not to the gram, at least roughly- the food that you intake every day to make sure that you stay as close as possible to your caloric goal. You can get one for about $10 in Amazon, so no excuses.
3. Eat whole foods with nutritional value and avoid processed crap. Keep your protein high.
4. Find a gym with a squat rack and olympic barbells, and pick a proven beginner weight-lifting program. [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/) and [Stronglifts](http://stronglifts.com/) are staples here.
5. Do not quit. If you've followed all the previous steps for a month or two, the results will be so obvious that it will be very hard for you to stop.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of excercises which burn fat. F.e. squats, burpees or even take a look into crossfit.

But one of the most important things to make sure you get right is your diet.

*(edit your question with some more details, this makes it easier, f.e. since when did you start working out, what are you doing now (scheme) and what is your progress so far?, do you have a current diet?)*